# Updating Asus BIOS to version 6042; can only get up to version 5606

Tags: bios, asus

I have an ASUS PRIME X370-A motherboard.

The current CPU is a AMD Athlon X4 950 quad core.

The current BIOS was V.4023.

The flash drive is formatted to FAT32

I want to update the CPU so I bought an AMD Ryzen 5 5600G

This was the easy bit.

I switched out the CPU only to find that it wouldn't boot, I then discovered that the minimum BIOS version for this chip is version 6042.

https://community.amd.com/t5/processors/amd-ryzen-5600g/td-p/588738

All good so far.

I downloaded the relevant BIOS files from here:

https://www.asus.com/supportonly/prime%20x370-a/helpdesk_bios/

I also discovered that the BIOS is supposed to be updated sequentially, so I worked through the list of updates beyond 4023 and all went well until I got to 5606

Now, whatever I do, I cannot update beyond 5606, I still have 6026 and 6042 to update to.

Every time I try to flash the BIOS, I get an error message that says "Selected file is not a proper BIOS"

I have messaged ASUS support **3 times** and all they have done is send me the link for the donwloads.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

EDIT
Thank you for all your help.
I decided that I couldn't be doing with all the grief and bought a new motherboard. Updating the BIOS was a piece of cake and it all worked perfectly.

Comment: 1. Have you tried recopying v. 6026? Perhaps the copy is bad. 2. Have you renamed the downloaded files, as directed in the link you provided?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I have downloaded each newer version of the BIOS at least 5 times, reformatted the flash drive to FAT32 at least 5 times and renamed the files using the renamer. However, https://rog-forum.asus.com/t5/promotions-general-discussions/is-renaming-bios-file-nessesary-if-i-am-updating-bios-from/td-p/619288 suggests that renaming is not necessary if using EZ Flash. That said, I tried with and without renaming and neither worked. I am nearly at the stage where I am just going to buy a new motherboard that doesn't have asus in the name...